# Calling SQL Server Stored Procedure using PHP PDO from Lumen for return value gives syntax error

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, lumen, freetds

I am trying to get the return value from the SqlServer stored procedure. But it is giving syntax error in my Ubuntu Server which uses FreeTDS.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 Incorrect syntax near '0'.
>   [20018] (severity 15) [(null)]

Below is my code:

```
$stateId = 1;
$testData = 0;
$retVal = 0;

$pdo = DB::connection(env('DBCONNECTION'))->getPdo();
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('EXEC ? = GetMyCities_sp @StateID = ?, @TestData = ?');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $retVal, \PDO::PARAM_INT,20);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $stateId, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $testData, \PDO::PARAM_INT | \PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 20);

$result_status = $stmt->execute();

$resultSet = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
print_r($resultSet);
echo "<br />";
$stmt->nextRowset();

echo "Return value is ".$retVal;
```

The same works fine in my windows machine. Any idea what is wrong in the code?

Comment: Have you seen this? 
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=58514

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure if these two are exactly the same.For me the exception is thrown, param is taken in the right place, but showing a syntax error while executing it.

Comment: placeholders can only represent VALUES, not keywords/identifiers.

Comment: @marcB Sorry I didn't get your point here. Here the place holders are being bound with the values only. Not keywords.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, bound parameters need to be parameters, not procedure names. Can you give this a test, replacing the first `?` with the stored procedure name?

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('EXEC your-proc-name = GetMyCities_sp @StateID = ?, @TestData = ?');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $stateId, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $testData, \PDO::PARAM_INT | \PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 20);
```

It has been a long time since I've played with PHP, but you might be able to do this if the first test works:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('EXEC $retVal = GetMyCities_sp @StateID = ?, @TestData = ?');
```

Comment: No, it didn't work. It again gives a similar syntax error.